# Type 'MyType' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<MyType>'

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, immer.js

I use `@reduxjs/toolkit` and my state contains: `allSlides: ISlide[];`

When I try to change anything in `allSlides` like ex.

```
setAllSlides(state, action: PayloadAction<ISlide[]>) {
  state.allSlides = action.payload;
},
storeNewSlide(state, action: PayloadAction<ISlide>) {
  state.allSlides.push(action.payload);
},
```

I get a TS error

```
Type 'ISlide' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<ISlide>'
```

I don't have problem with changing array of primitive values or just one property in objects, but I don't know how to change correctly whole array or specific object in array.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue,
I think redux doesn't like direct mutation of state object.

so spread operator solved for me

```
setAllSlides(state, action: PayloadAction<ISlide[]>) {
  state = { ...state, allSlices:action.payload };
},
storeNewSlide(state, action: PayloadAction<ISlide>) {
  state = { ...state, allSlices: [...state.allSlices, action.payload } ];
},
```

Comment: This is likely true of redux, but not when using Redux Toolkit as it uses Immer internally. See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers

Comment: Following @Kristopher's lead, I see this works for me: `Object.assign(state, { allSlices: action.payload });`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the type in the action

ie:

```
export const storeNewSlide = createAsyncThunk(
  "slides/storeNewSlide",
  async (slide: ISlide) => {
    return {
      slide,
    };
  }
);
```

and then in your `allSlides`:

```
storeNewSlide(state, action: PayloadAction<ISlide>) {
  state.allSlides.push(action.payload.slide);
},
```

Same for the array of slides

Comment: Interestingly this fixed it. So it's a mere argument type issue, no runtime code should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the type of 'state' in the reducer. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've had similar issue. Resolved by import type on type. in my case :

```
import { Comment } from "./commentType"; //import Comment

export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  release_date: Date;
  genre: string;
  director: string;
  description: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

export interface MovieResponse extends Movie {
  rating: number;
  comments: Comment[]; //this Comment type not imported before
  isWatchlist: boolean;
}
```